# Error (NSolve::ifun) when using NSolve, I need help interpreting the error

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I wrote the following code to observe how the solutions to the equation $(e^{i a})^2 = e^{i b}$ varied as $b$ varied between 0 and $2\pi$

```
Manipulate[NSolve[(E^(I a))^2 == E^(I b), a], {b, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

However, the following error appears: 
[image: Inverse function error]

How would I use `Reduce` to solve the above equation? I thought reduce was a way to fold up a list with a binary operator.

Comment: Off[Solve::ifun]; Manipulate[
 Solve[(E^(I a))^2 == E^(I b), a], {b, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

Comment: Could do: nSolve[b_?NumericQ] := Quiet[a /. NSolve[(E^(I a))^2 == E^(I b), a]]
Manipulate[nSolve[b], {b, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "reduce" that you're thinking of is called [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fold.html) in Mathematica. Here, [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) is a function to solve equations/inequalities.

The error message that you get for `NSolve` is the same as [`Solve::ifun`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Solve/ifun.html), which you often get when there are an infinite number of solutions. A simple example that gives you this warning and is easy to relate to is:

```
Solve[Sin[k π] == 0, k]    
(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{{k -> 0}} *)
```

Of course, $k=0\ $ is not the only solution, and the correct solution is $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. If you take the advice given in the warning and use `Reduce`, you get the full set:

```
Reduce[Sin[k Pi] == 0, k]
(* C[1] ∈ Integers && (k == 2 C[1] || k == (π + 2 π C[1])/π) *)
```

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you. I wouldn't think that an equation with only one free variable would have more than one solution, but since `Solve` and `NSolve` are using inverse functions, that must mean that it is using the many-valued complex logarithm right? If so, this makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 6):

```
Off[Solve::ifun];
Manipulate[
 Show[{Graphics[{White, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.5], Black, Circle[], PointSize[Large],
       Red,
       Text[b, 1.2 {Cos@b, Sin@b}],
       Point[{Cos@b, Sin@b}],
       Blue,
       Text[#, 1.2 {Cos@#, Sin@#}],
       Point[{Cos@#, Sin@#}]}]} & /@
   (a /. Solve[(E^(I a))^2 == E^(I b), a])],
 {b, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]